# Why is the cell data duplicated in each column?

Tags: phpexcel

I'm new to PHPExcel and somehow I got the same data duplicated in the Excel spreadsheet using the following code:

```
<?php
  $roster_sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE";
  $roster_result = mysql_query($roster_sql) or die(mysql_error());

  // Populate 2D Array
  $kcount = 0;
  while($sheet_array = mysql_fetch_array($roster_result))
  {
    $sheet[$kcount] = $sheet_array;
    $kcount++;
  }
  $rowID = 1;
  foreach($sheet as $rowArray)
  {
    $columnID = 'A';
    foreach($rowArray as $columnValue)
    {
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columnID.$rowID, $columnValue);
      $columnID++;
    }
    $rowID++;
  }
?>
```

The generated spreadsheet has each cell value duplicated in the column. Did I populate the array incorrectly or is there something wrong when I write out the array?

Further, how do I write the header row in the same spreadsheet without hard coding the column names from the SQL?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Default behaviour for `mysql_fetch_array()` is to return an array with both enumerated ***and*** associative values for each column. i.e. the $result_type argument is MYSQL_BOTH.

If you only want either an associative **or** an enumerated result (but not both), then you need to specify this, e.g.

```
while($sheet_array = mysql_fetch_array($roster_result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

or

```
while($sheet_array = mysql_fetch_array($roster_result, MYSQL_NUM))
```

or use one of the related functions, e.g.

```
while($sheet_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($roster_result))
```

or

```
while($sheet_array = mysql_fetch_row($roster_result))
```

**EDIT**

If you want to write out the column names as a header, then you need to call something like [mysql_list_fields()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php) to get the list of columns for the table

Or alternatively, retrieve your data as an associative array, and then the key values will be your column names